# pst-3d + macos + fontspec

Tags: pstricks, fontspec

I think this is a FAQ but I'm not finding the right question to look for, I think. If I use xelatex and pst-3d the resulting pdf does not show any 3d transformation. If I use latex and dvips the 3d transformation is apparent. However, I am also using fontspec. If I use the "latex" command, fontspec complains cannot-use-pdftex (I am using texlive 2015 and macports).

If this is a general problem with this combination, is there a way to use fontspec and pst-3d on macos, or can you point me to info?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-3d}

\usepackage[paperwidth=16in,paperheight=16in,margin=0in]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Georgia}[ItalicFont={* Italic},BoldFont={* Bold}]
\setmonofont{Arial}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,3)

\psset{viewpoint=1 0.001 0.5}
\ThreeDput[normal= 1 3 0](0,1,1){\fbox{\LARGE ABCDEF}}

\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is with `fontspec`; the result is the same with or without it.

Comment: With fontspec, using latex, fontspec complains: cannot-use-pdftex.

Using xelatex, the result is that no skewing to simulate 3d transformation appears in the pdf, it is simply flat as if I used \fbox by itself.

Without fontspec, using latex command and dvips, 3d transformation appears.

Comment: You cannot use `fontspec` with `latex`, only `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: Okay, what about using fontspec and pst-3d together?

Comment: As I said, if I run the example file with `xelatex`, loading `fontspec` and not loading it makes no difference (except for the font used). Thus the problem is in `pst-3d` (or in the driver file).

Comment: I don't think it's in `pst-3d`, 'cause it compiles fine if you load `auto-pst-pdf`  and compile with `pdflatex`. Note tyhe configuration files of `xetex-pstricks` date back to 2010, and `xetex`has changed since then.

Comment: How are you using auto-pst-pdf? If I just add \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} fontspec still complains that fontspec requires xetex or luatex.